# PLSQL : Is it a good idea to deal with temp tables in plsql saved procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Intend this to be a discussion.

I have a result table, that is generated from a slightly complex query(several Joins and WHERE clauses), That I will be manipulating/referencing multiple times in the procedure as we go on.

The only thing that i can come up with, is storing the result of the query in a table and dropping the table at the end of the procedure. Is this a viable option? What are the drawbacks? Better alternatives?

Comment: Discussions are not welcome on this site. We want questions which can be answered with a single clear solution. Fortunately this is a question for which there is one correct answer.

Comment: Okay. Will tc next time.

Answer (score 6):

Creating and dropping tables in stored procedures is almost always the wrong solution.

Firstly you have just turned a query into a database change; that is problematic for a variety of reasons, but especially privilege escalation. Secondly, DDL can fail for a variety of reasons, so this approach introduces jeopardy which doesn't exist in a pure query. Thirdly, creating, populating and dropping a table adds overhead.

The best solution: just write an efficient SELECT statement.

Alternative solutions, in decreasing order of performance:

- using WITH clauses to manipulate the query flow
- populating PL/SQL collections
- in 18c private temporary tables
- global temporary tables (which are **permanent** database tables, it's just the data which is temporary).

Your question poses a scenario of querying an initial result set, then programmatically manipulating it. My first thought is you should try to do this in pure SQL. Oracle has a vast arsenal of functions, not least the analytic functions, and you will be astonished at how much it is possible to do in a query. But if you really need to work in a procedural fashion populating and manipulating arrays is the next most performative approach. Populating a global temporary table is expensive, because it entails writing to and reading from disk. Only consider GTTs if you are constrained by session memory, or you need to share data across multiple procedures.

Comment: All right. Thank you  @APC

Let's say I go ahead with PL/SQL Collections, Does the number of records effect the performance widely? I am expecting nearly 200,000 to 300,000 records in my initial query, which i would like to save for future referencing and manipulation. 

P.S : This is my first time doing the tango with PL/SQL.

Comment: Or you could create table - an in procedure at the beginning truncate it, and fill again. There is no need create/drop table everytime you run some code.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue so I break the query in multiple part and user GTT table. Also check if you can user WITH clause while breaking your query. This will help lot and get better performance.